# php migration from 2003 server to 2012 not connecting to SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm moving some php sites backed by SQL from a 2003 server to a 2012R2 server.  I haven't had time to update code to use a newer php version so am using 5.2.10.  I have everything working except I can't get a connection to the SQL server - the latter has not changed.

The errors I'm getting are:

- PHP Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server...
- PHP Warning: mssql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-Link resource in...

How can I verify that mssql_connect and mssql_select_db are working? Or do those errors mean that they are?  The credentials are the same as those on the currently working server to be replaced so I'm fairly certain that's not it but if I can be assured that the php side is working, I'll invest my attentions back to SQL and/or a possible network issue (although they're on the same network behind a firewall so that *shouldn't* be it)

I'm stuck with what to do next.

Comment: From your new PHP server, try pinging the SQL server. If the ping succeeds then try testing the MSSQL port which *should* be listening. [Checking port availability](http://serverfault.com/questions/35218/in-windows-using-the-command-line-how-do-you-check-if-a-remote-port-is-open)

Comment: I can ping the server and can access using the server name via Test-NetConnection <serverName>

Comment: Can you please share the full error message, also please describe the way you are assigning server ans db name. thanks